# Solving for a variable within a Trigonometric Function

Tags: trigonometry

My Trig is rusty and I thought that asking here may help speed along the process as I break out my dusty identity cheat sheet.

I have the following equality that I would like to solve for $c$:

$$0.1666a = a - r^2\left(2 \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{2r}\right) - \sin(2 \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{2r}\right)\right)$$

I'm having trouble boiling this down to one instance of $c$ to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can solve this explicitly. If you write $\theta = 2\cos^{-1}(c/2r)$, the equation you are faced with solving for $\theta$ is
$$0.1666a = a - r^2(\theta - \sin\theta)$$
and that can't be solved explicitly as far as I know.

Comment: Well, that may explain my troubles :).  Thanks. I'll give it a bit, but if that seems to be the consensus (makes sense to me given c could be anything) I'll mark this as solved.  I can get what I need by iterating over possible values of c instead.